# An application of Wald's equation

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I was posed the following question and I am interested in whether or not my proposed approach works.

Let $X_{i}$ be i.i.d uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ and define $N_{k}$ to be the smallest integer such that
$$1<\sum_{i=1}^{N_{k}} X^{k}_{i}.$$

Then calculate
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[N_{k}]}{k}.$$

My approach is to call $N_{k}$ a stopping time for the sequence $X_{1},X_{2},\dots$ so that

$$X_{1}^{k}+X_{2}^{k} + \dots + X_{N_{k}-1}^{k} \leq 1 < X_{1}^{k}+\dots + X_{N_{k}}^{k}.$$

Then using Wald's equation and taking the expectation of each side,

$$\mathbb{E}[N_{k}-1]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] \leq 1 < \mathbb{E}[N_{k}]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] $$
or
$$\mathbb{E}[N_{k}]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] -\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] \leq 1 \leq  \mathbb{E}[N_{k}]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}]$$

$$-\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] \leq 1 - \mathbb{E}[N_{k}]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] \leq 0$$

and conclude via the squeeze theorem by noting that

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}]}{k} = 0, \quad\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] = 1.$$

Is this general approach going to be successful? I am not too confident in taking the expectation of the inequality because the line

$$X_{1}^{k}+X_{2}^{k} + \dots + X_{N_{k}-1}^{k} \leq 1 < X_{1}^{k}+\dots + X_{N_{k}}^{k}$$

seems to be abusing notation. I think it is conditioning on $N_{k}$ satisfying this inequality and something subtle might be making this argument invalid.

Comment: Wald says that $E(X_{1}^{k}+\cdots + X_{N_{k}}^{k})=E(X_1^k)E(N_k)$,  not that $E(X_{1}^{k}+\dots + X_{N_{k}-1}^{k})=E(X_1^k)E(N_k-1)$ because $N_k$ is a stopping time but $N_k-1$ is not.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Could I then repair this by adding $\mathbb{E}[X_{N_{k}}]$ to all three sides of the inequality and use linearity of the expectation to get $\mathbb{E}[N_{k}]\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{k}] + \mathbb{E}[X_{N_{k}}^{k}]$ on the right most expectation?

Comment: The idea of adding $E(X_{N_k}^k)$ is rather bizarre. What you have at present is $$E(N_k)E(X_1^k)>1$$ which is equivalent to $$E(N_k)>k+1$$ and $$E(N_k)E(X_1^k)-E(X_{N_k}^k)\leqslant1$$ which is equivalent to $$E(N_k)\leqslant k+1+(k+1)E(X^k _{N_k})$$ The missing piece to deduce from these that $$\lim\frac{E(N_k)}k=1$$ is to prove that $$\lim E(X^k _{N_k})=0$$

Comment: @Did After fiddling around, just the fact that $N_{k}-1$ is not a stopping time was the key insight I was after. I can accept that as an answer if you like.